# How to merge multi index axis into single index axis Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a single data frame and after pivoting it I've got the dataframe in this format:
[image]

I want it to be a single header like `Raw01, Raw02, Raw 03, Raw04, Raw05, calcd01, calcd02, calcd03` and so on. Also the index column can just b `a`.

I've searched for other questions but in that case they have two data frames and I only have one. So, how will I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten your columns like this:

```
df.columns = [''.join(map(str, col)).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
```

Comment: I got a warning `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.` and after that if I do `df.head()` it prints out the same multi index.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha That's odd, `df.columns` should refer to columns not new column named `columns`. Did you paste the code correctly?

Comment: My bad... I'm with this dataset since morning and going crazy. It worked perfectly :D

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha No worries, glad to help :)